# Sql table split into batches

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to split a table into batches of n rows ( in the forward example n = 2). I want to do this so that I can export the batches into files. 
The solution I found is the following:

```
create table tbl_test (
first_name nvarchar(255),
last_name nvarchar(255),
[address] nvarchar(255),
 )

Insert tbl_test values ('Andrei','Corovei','str Meteor')
Insert tbl_test values ('Pop','Ionut','str Meteor')
Insert tbl_test values ('Whitehead','John','str Lunii')
Insert tbl_test values ('Grisham','Robert','str Corcoduselor')
Insert tbl_test values ('Eugen','Johnesco','str Prunelor')


select * into #tbl_temp from tbl_test 

alter table #tbl_temp add tabid int identity(1,1)


declare @current int = 1
while @current < ident_current('#tbl_temp')
begin
select * from #tbl_temp
    where tabid between @current and @current +1
set @current = @current + 2
end

drop table #tbl_temp
drop table tbl_test
```

Can anyone suggest a solution that does not include copying data into a ***temp table*** and ***NOT ALTERING*** the source table in any way. And I also want this to work for any table i.e. I cannot speculate that the source has a indentity tabid or date_key for sorting.

Comment: How do you plan to export a batch of rows?

Comment: each batch of rows into separate file...

Comment: Yes, so you said. You didn't specify what mechanism you planned to use, so I couldn't take that in to account while answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to have a unique ID as long as you know at least one column name which you can order by.

```
declare @tbl_test table(
    first_name nvarchar(255),
    last_name nvarchar(255),
    [address] nvarchar(255)
);

insert @tbl_test values ('Andrei','Corovei','str Meteor');
insert @tbl_test values ('Pop','Ionut','str Meteor');
insert @tbl_test values ('Whitehead','John','str Lunii');
insert @tbl_test values ('Grisham','Robert','str Corcoduselor');
insert @tbl_test values ('Eugen','Johnesco','str Prunelor');

select
        *
    from
        (select
                row_number() over (partition by r%2 order by first_name) as batch,
                *
            from 
                (select
                        row_number() over (order by first_name) as r,
                        *
                    from
                        @tbl_test
                ) as t
        ) as b
    where
        batch = 2
    order by
        batch, r
;
```

The result of this is that you see only the rows which go in to batch 2. A simple loop around this which increments the batch number will get you one batch at a time; just stop looping when no more batches exist.

The only problem would be if the number of rows in your table changes while you're processing.

Comment: The only thing you have to be careful about with this method is that the data which provides the sort can't change during your extraction.  However, if that's a problem, then you'll need to resort to using an immutable monotonic value (like an identity or a date of insertion) tocorrect for it.

Comment: @Stuart: Yes, I edited to note this in case it wasn't obvious.